# Any way to move widgets beyond container without resizing it?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I am working on a game using GTK3 as a rendering technique (terrible idea, but it's a school project).

My gameobjects are made of Image widgets and are placed in a Fixed container. It's working pretty well, however when i move widgets beoynd right or bottom border, the window automatically grows along with it.

I want the window to stay at the sam size, event if widget leaves its area and becomes invisible. It works when i move widget past the upper or left border.

I tried using **gtk_widget_set_vexpand** and **gtk_widget_set_hexpand**. My window is set as not resizable (**gtk_window_set_resizable**).

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: This is still a misuse of GTK+, but: try using GtkLayout instead of GtkFixed? And if that doesn't work, try using a GtkScrolledWindow and configure it to not scroll.

Comment: THANK YOU! :) GtkLayout fixed the issue.
I also tried GtkScrolled window, but it ads this ugly scrollbar. GtkLayout works great though

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the right way to use GTK+. GTK+ is intended for laying out widgets in a GUI program.

There are better options for animating 2D elements. One that works with GTK+ natively is [the Clutter library](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Clutter). You can also integrate SDL or OpenGL or something like that if you so choose.

That being said, you can also use GtkLayout instead of GtkFixed, or put the GtkFixed in a GtkScrolledWindow and hide the scrollbars and set the scroll policy to prevent scrolling. It's still technically misuse, and in fact GtkFixed (and possibly GtkLayout too but the docs don't say) is really not supposed to be used anymore unless absolutely necessary because it doesn't give you automatic support for tricky UI layout problems, but it doesn't have extra dependencies.